# Transferring Apple ID purchases to another Apple ID

Tags: apple-id

My old email along with my Apple ID were registered as aol accounts. When I switched to gmail I had to create a new Apple ID under the new gmail account. Is there anyway to transfer the purchases and information from my old Apple ID to my new one?

Answer (score 10):

You didn't have to change the Apple ID, you needed only to change its associated email address.

The account "name" can be Fred@one.com, the associated email can be joe@two.com
The "name" is just that, a name. It doesn't actually even have to be a valid email address, other than for the initial setup.

All of which is leading to…
No, you cannot transfer purchases from one account to another, except if you set them both up as part of [Family Sharing](https://www.apple.com/icloud/family-sharing/)

From [Apple KB](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202667) -

> ## Change your Apple ID
>
> **Learn how to change the email address that you use as your Apple ID.**
>
> In most cases, your Apple ID is also the [primary email address](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5620) of your Apple ID account. You can change your Apple ID to any other email address you control, as long as it's not already in use as an Apple ID. If your email address ends with @icloud.com, @me.com, or @mac.com, it's already an Apple ID.
>
> Use these steps to reset your Apple ID:
>
> 1. Sign out of iCloud, the iTunes Store, App Store, FaceTime, Find My Friends, Find My iPhone, and iMessage on each device that uses your current Apple ID for these services.
> 2. Go to [My Apple ID](https://appleid.apple.com/).
> 3. Select Manage your Apple ID and sign in. [Forgot your password?](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5787)
> 4. Select Edit next to Apple ID and Primary Email Address.
> 5. Enter the email address that you want to use as your Apple ID, then select Save Changes. Apple will send a verification email to that address.
> 6. Open the email from Apple, then click Verify Now. [Didn't receive the email?](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS5404)
> 7. When the My Apple ID page opens, sign in with your new Apple ID email address and password. When you see a message that verification is complete, you can start using your updated Apple ID.
> 8. [Update the features and services](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5796) that you use with Apple ID, so that each one is using your updated Apple ID.
>
> If you need to change the Apple ID that's signed in to your iOS device, use these steps to [sign out, then back in with a different Apple ID.](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT203983)

Comment: I think the easier way for you is to cvhange the email for your apple ID, you can read [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202667) how to do it

Comment: @AntK - thanks for finding the link; I'll add the details to the answer