# I am retiring and my apple ID and email will be cancelled by my employer. How do I keep some of the content from apple id?

Tags: apple-id

I am a public school teacher about to retire. My apple id is tied to my school email. These accounts will no longer be available to me upon retirement. How can I save or transfer data to my personal apple id/gmail?

Comment: Your content and apps are tied to the Apple ID.  If you create a new ID, assuming with a new email address, you'll lose access to whatever's tied to the one owned by your employer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transferring Apple ID purchases to another Apple ID](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/197228/transferring-apple-id-purchases-to-another-apple-id)

Comment: Technically you can just login with your apple id to https://appleid.apple.com/ and then change the apple id/conatct email. Now wether you are entitled to the apps etc that were bought by the school is another matter. Also if the school is using management software then they might need to agree to you doing this. For others in the future use separate ids for work and your own use.

Comment: Thank you for the speedy response. I do have a personal apple id now, but also invested my own money in my work account. I still have a $50 balance in my work apple id.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very hard process to generalize, but we have someone that has written about it exceptionally clearly.

- https://www.brianstucki.com/blog/how-to-manually-merge-two-apple-ids-to-one/

The process does take a lot of steps as e@ch bucket of data may or may not be fungible, but I would start with a good backup that you know you can restore before you try any changes. Perhaps you do not even need to merge things, but just change the email from school to home and keep the account, erase the school machines when your retirement day draws close.